# Time-dependent if-function with multiple conditions

Tags: conditional, time-series

I try to programme the following: If the price is <= -0.2 for 20 periods in a row, taxes should be introduced for the following 60 periods. Currently I am using this if-function:

```
tax[t_] := If[
   p[t - 1] <= -0.2 && p[t - 2] <= -0.2 && ... p[t - 20] <= -0.2,
   tax[t] = 0.0025; tax[t + 1] = 0.0025; ... tax[t + 59] = 0.0025,
   0]
```

Here, the system introduces taxes for 60/120/180/... periods. But what I want the system to do is, that if the price is <= -0.2 for e.g. 24 periods, taxes should be introduced for 64 periods. Meaning, the system should introduce taxes in period 21 for the following 60 periods. In period 22 the system should check again if the price was <= -0.2 in the previous 20 periods and if so, start again with introducing taxes for the next 60 periods and so on.

My remaining functions are:

`Price: p[t_]:=p[t]=p[t-1]+mc[t-1]*dc[t-1]`

`Demand: dc[t_]:=dc[t]=0.05*(p[t]-p[t-1])`

`Amount: mc[t_]:=mc[t]=Exp[300*pc[t]]/(Exp[300*pc[t]]+Exp[300*0])`

`Attractiveness of buying: pc[t_]:=pc[t]=(Exp[p[t]]-Exp[p[t-1]])*dc[t-2]+0.975*pc[t-1]+unknown[t-1]*dc[t-2]*Exp[p[t-1]]`

`Taxes only if demand is negative (=sale): unknown[t_]:=If[dc[t-2]<0,tax[t], 0]`

`Initial values for all parameters {t,1,10} = 0`

As I am not a Mathematica expert, it would be great if you can explain possible solutions as simple as possible. ;) Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`tax2` is a utility function that takes a list of prices. In order to keep it simple, I have not parametrized the threshold (-0.2) or the number of bins for which tax has to be applied (next 60) or the last however many bins have to be checked (last 20 in this case).

- It defines a `ConstantArray` of zeros of length 160 called `taxbins`; (100 price points + 60 for the tax, should these be needed at the last check that occurs at 100.
- `Table` starts checking at 20th price item and checks the previous 20 prices.. If nothing exceeds the threshold, it adds +1 to the next 60  `taxbins`. This means that values in the `taxbins` could be greater than `1`. Therefore at the end we `Unitize` these values or bring them back to one. You can remove `Unitize` and see the effect. At the end you can multiply `taxbins` array with tax value of your choice.

---

```
tax2[k_List] := Module[
  {
   taxbins = ConstantArray[0, 100 + 61]
   },
  (*Echo[taxbins];*)
  Table[
   If[Length@Cases[k[[i - 19 ;; i]], a_ /; a > -0.2] == 0,
     taxbins[[i + 1 ;; i + 61]] += 1];
   , {i, 20, Length@k}
   ];
  Unitize[taxbins]
  (*Unitize[taxbins[[1;;100]]]*)
  ]
```

--------------- usage ---------------

```
p2 = RandomReal[{-0.5, -0.17}, {100}];
g2 = ListLinePlot[{p2, tax2[p2]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 161}, {-1, 1.1}},
  PlotStyle -> {Thin, Thick},
  Ticks -> {Range[0, 180, 20], Range[-1.25, 1.25, 0.25]},
  ImageSize -> 500,
  PlotLegends -> {"price", "tax"},
  Epilog -> {Red, Thick, Line[{{0, -0.2}, {100, -0.2}}]}
  ]
```

You can change the range of points in `p2` to try out different scenarios. First scenario is that all prices are less than -0.25, so tax is levied at the 20th point and stays there.

[image]

---

The second scenario: prices cross the threshold: change `p2` and execute a few times:

```
p2 = RandomReal[{-0.5, -0.17}, {100}];
```

[image]

---

Please experiment by changing various components in the answer. In the function, you can also choose 100 values only as the last commented line shows. Be sure to return one of those only by commenting the other line.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! I tried to transfer it to my code and here I faced the callenge, that I want the tax to influence the price in the following way: If p<=-0.2 for 20 periods, the price should be p=p+tax for the following 60 periods, with the tax=0.0025 being added to the price.

Comment: @Nicole Thanks for the reply: The price has a starting point? and how does it change (let's say) for the first 20 periods and after that when tax is being levied? it must be a function of some sort. Please update the post with a clearer description. My question is: Let's say there was no tax, how would the price function look like on its own?

Comment: Many thanks for your effort Syed! I added the remaining functions in the post. Unfortunately, there are quite a few as the price is not directly influenced by the taxes.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand you correctly.
Taxes are levied if the price was <=-0.2 during the last 60 to 40 periods.

This can be implemented e.g.:

```
tax[t_]:= If[Max[Max[Table[p[i], {i, t - 60, t - 40}]]]<=-0.2,0.00025,0]
```

To test this we may declare prices that are low for t<0 and high otherwise:

p[t_] := If[t < 0, -1, 1];

```
tax[0]
tax[39]
tax[40]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the "from...until" command! Unfortunately I receive the following error message when I tried to implement `tax[t_]:=If[Max[p[[t-20;;t-1]]]<=-0.2,0.0025,0]`: 

_Part: Cannot take positions -9 through 10 in p_

I do not understand why the if-condition works when I list t-20, t-19, ... t-1 individually but does not work if I summarise exactly the same list by t-20;;t-1

Comment: Sorry it is my fault.  Indices of arrays must always be positive.  If you want to use negative indices you must use a function for p. I will change my answer accordingly. Or if you have an array to start with, you must use an offset to ensure that the index is always positive.

Comment: Ah now it works that taxes are implemented for 60 periods, many thanks Daniel! Let's see if I can manage it that taxes will be implemented for more than 60 periods in case the price is <-0.2 for more than 20 periods.